# Is it allowed to change a question this drastically?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

This morning I got a notification that for an answer of mine a [sugessted edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24448935) was made.

As you see in the link above the question title states "**Excel VBA - There isn't enough memory to complete this action**" and the proposed edit had been the change from `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` to `Set oApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`.

I just thought what a big mistake I had made and wanted to click on "Approve" but then thought to first check the question. The OP edited the question changing form `Outlook` stuff to `Excel` and removing the whole code as well.

Is it allowed to change a question this drastically after receiving answers althought not upvoted (mine) but clearly refering to the OP's code? ?

What is the correct procedure here?

Comment: *"Is it allowed to change a question this drastically after receiving answers"*? So, you did exactly what you're complaining about, with this question here? At least from the edit history and comments, it looks like you drastically altered your own question after the current answer was provided.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica did you read my original question ? Especially the title and how the question could be read after the title change?

Comment: That's my point. Your original question is different from the edited version of your question. It at least appears that you changed it after an answer was given to the old version. So, from what I can tell, you exhibited the same behavior that you seem to be complaining about.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica not really. The answerer had first changed the title of the question because they misunderstood my bad english. Their answer made sense with the changed title. But this hadn't been what I asked hence I added a comment and edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica I misunderstood the question, and edited the title with what I could best understand of the body of the question and answered based on that. The author then clarified what they actually meant of their question. I've deleted my answer to make it less confusing to others.

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog Ah! I see I didn't notice the different name on the original edit of the title, which led me to an incorrect assumption.